# How to use Python to display icons based on test result in a GUI?

Tags: python

I am developing a test application. There are 4 tests I am implementing. Based on the test results, I want to show a PASS or FAIL icon next to the test name as each of the test is being ran. It would be something like this:

1. Test 1: TEST_NAME_ONE  ............ PASS
2. Test 2: TEST_NAME_TWO  ............ FAIL
3. Test 3: TEST_NAME_THREE ........... PASS
4. Test 4: TEST_NAME_FOUR  ...........

I try using gui2py to implement this. But it doesn't seem like it is capable. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Give **Tkinter** a try. Besides the icons, there are many GUI/MVC-framework tools, including a capability for event-scheduling / coordination in case the test management may have some benefits from using that approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a GUI"?  What are your requirements for a "GUI"?   ClickBerry's solution looks pretty attractive for avoiding a GUI...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode characters instead of icons.

For PASS use ✔:

```
print(u"\u2714")
```

For FAIL use ✖:

```
print(u"\u2716")
```